# Why does xclip -t text/html -selection c not work?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, clipboard

In Ubuntu 20.04 / Gnome, this works

```
echo "ABC" | xclip -selection c
```

However, this does not work:

```
echo "ABC" | xclip -t text/html -selection c
```

By 'not working' I mean that I'm unable to paste. -section primary/secondary similarly doesn't work.

(By way of user story: I have html, and want to put it onto the clipboard as formatted text, e.g, put `<b>bold</b>` onto clipboard, so the string bold pastes as **bold**.)

Any ideas how to get xclip working or how to use something else? (OS X has things like textutil and pbcopy that can achieve this - are there alternatives on Ubuntu?)

Basically, solutions like https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84951/copy-markdown-input-to-the-clipboard-as-rich-text (via https://superuser.com/questions/912712/how-to-send-rich-text-to-the-clipboard-from-command-line) rely on xclip ...

`-loops` should avoid the clipboard being handed to mutter.

```
> echo "ABC" | xclip -loops 0 -t text/html -o 
Error: target text/html not available
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to IRC #gnome.

So turns out that

```
echo "<b>ABCDEF</b>" | xclip -selection c -t text/html
```

**does work** - but, the thing that caught me is that you cannot paste back into Terminal! In the Terminal UI (right click), the clipboard is showing as disabled.

So run the above command and paste into an application that can accept text/html (like Google Docs). That works!

The error from

```
echo "ABC" | xclip -t text/html -o
```

is because -o reads from the selection and pastes. So the 'echo ABC' doesn't make sense.

Try

```
echo "<b>ABCDEF</b>" | xclip -verbose -loop 0 -selection c -t text/html
```

to get more info. I am not sure whether the 'loop' is needed - seems to work without.

Comment: Incidentally, this is the 'reverse' of a Q asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265567/why-does-xclip-t-text-html-selection-c-not-work

Comment: Apologies - it's the reverse of this Q here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1397056/work-around-for-xclip-o-selection-clipboard-t-text-html-error-target-t