# Work around for "xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html" -> "Error: target text/html not available"

Tags: clipboard, xclip

In gnome-terminal,

```
xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html
```

gives

```
Error: target text/html not available
```

In some sense, this makes sense, because gnome-terminal does not accept html pastes.

However, it does mean that

```
xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html > out.html
```

does not work either.

How do I get the contents from the clipboard as html or how do I work around the issue?

Comment: This is the reverse of what's asked here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265567/why-does-xclip-t-text-html-selection-c-not-work (sort of)

Comment: Before something can come out of the clipboard, something has to be in there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html
```

will paste html code into your terminal, provided ... there is something in the clipboard in the first place.

Try

```
$ echo "<html><body>HTML text <i>in the clipboard</i></html></body>" | xclip -i -selection clipboard -t text/html
$ xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html
<html><body>HTML text <i>in the clipboard</i></html></body>
$ xclip -o -selection clipboard 
<html><body>HTML text <i>in the clipboard</i></html></body>
```

The output can be redirected to a text file. Pasting in for example Writer will cause pasting of text formatted according to the html code.

Mind that this will not work if you copy/paste the commands in the terminal: your copying would overwrite the clipboard. To see this in action without too much typing, copy the commands (without the prompt sign) and paste them at once in the terminal or source the commands from a file.

Comment: Thank you. So there is stuff in the clipboard, because I can paste it into libreoffice, and I'll see formatted text. Given that -t text/html produces an error "Error: target text/html not available", does that suggest that the clipboard isn't recognised as html?  Is there a way I can inspect the clipboard?

Comment: This is very odd... I swear there was content on the clipboard. Maybe the clipboard mechanism was somehow broken - I've rebooted, and it works  Thank you!